# Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to create a JQGrid in my MVC 4 view and getting a

> Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference

error when adding the JQGrid javascript files

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/Shared/JS").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Content/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/Shared/Index.js",
            "~/Scripts/js/Shared/Validation.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.placeholder.js",
            "~/Content/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.3/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js",
            "~/Content/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.3/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"));
```

The error occurs on the following line

```
e=n.browser.msie&&"6.0"==n.browser.version
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the jQuery docs for [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/):

> **This property was removed in jQuery 1.9** and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

So you'll have to drop down to an older version of jQuery or use the [migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/).

Comment: Unfortunately the migrate plugin didn't work and I had to drop down to jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Answer (score 10):

I also had similar problem as this property was removed in jQuery 1.9...
Add below code inside your page script tag.

```
 jQuery.browser = {};
  (function () {
   jQuery.browser.msie = false;
   jQuery.browser.version = 0;
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
    jQuery.browser.msie = true;
    jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

e=n.browser.msie&&"6.0"==n.browser.version

I guess it should be like this

```
e == n.browser.msie && "6.0"==n.browser.version
```

or
`e === n.browser.msie && "6.0"=== n.browser.version` for strict equality

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another older script of mine however the majority of users will be running a version of IE over 6.0 so it really was not a big deal for me to give support to 6.0 or below. What I did was just change the line that said

```
var isIE6 = ($.browser.msie && &.browser.version < 7);
```

to

```
var isIE6 = false;
```